# Incompatibility between arydshln and tabulary

Tags: tables, tabulary, arydshln

I've seen a lot of posts about `arydshln` and `tabularx` (just need to import `tabularx` first) but I've been in trouble with `tabulary`.

I tried to change import order, nothing helps.

I get a lot of errors referring to my `tabulary` (which is OK if I no longer import `arydshln`):

```
Missing # inserted in alignment preamble.

<to be read again> 
                   &
l.92         \end{tabulary}
                           
There should be exactly one # between &'s, when an
\halign or \valign is being set up. In this case you had
none, so I've put one in; maybe that will work.
 chap0/introduction.tex, line 92

Missing # inserted in alignment preamble.

<to be read again> 
                   \cr 
l.92         \end{tabulary}
                           
There should be exactly one # between &'s, when an
\halign or \valign is being set up. In this case you had
none, so I've put one in; maybe that will work.
 chap0/introduction.tex, line 92

Missing number, treated as zero.

<to be read again> 
                   \TY@F1 
l.92         \end{tabulary}
                           
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
 chap0/introduction.tex, line 92

Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

<to be read again> 
                   \TY@F1 
l.92         \end{tabulary}
                           
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)
 chap0/introduction.tex, line 92

Missing = inserted for \ifdim.

<to be read again> 
                   \TY@F1 
l.92         \end{tabulary}
                           
I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.
 chap0/introduction.tex, line 92

Missing number, treated as zero.

<to be read again> 
                   \TY@F2 
l.92         \end{tabulary}
                           
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

Any idea?

Comment: they are incompatible. You will have to choose which one you prefer.